# NotesDatabase Search condition

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

With this code:

```
Set col = db.Search("Form=""formname"" & id=212", time, 0)
```

I explicity give the search function 212 for example, but what if I want to give a variable

```
dim var as Integer
```

How would my search look like, beacuse this doesn't work:

```
Set col = db.Search("Form=""formname"" & id=var", time, 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set col = db.Search("Form=""formname"" & id=" + Cstr(val), time, 0)
```

should work.

Cstr() converts the integer value to a string.

Comment: In order to make strings like that easier to read, I usually select another string delimiter, like this:  Set col = db.Search(|Form="formname" & id=| + Cstr(val), time, 0) 
Nothing wrong with Knut's code, just easier to read, IMHO.

Comment: Good point, @Karl-Henry, thanks. I use pipe for those cases usually too but didn't want to change too much in original code. That is by the way one of few things I miss in Java.

Comment: I would go with the Pipe and use the & to concat the value to the string: So: db.search(|Form="fname" & id=| & val, time, 0) - I find it easier to read and more foolproof to use & to concat strings and less to type, but some say its slightly slower, although tests show it is the same as cstr(val). Only downside is that in this instance, you have 2 '&' one in the string and one as an operator, but I'm ok with that.