# lotusscript search parameters

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

im getting errors in the following code at search parameters. I dont know how to set a a parameter to an variable

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase

Dim trenutni_dokument As NotesDocument

Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim broj As Integer 
Set trenutni_dokument = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
broj = trenutni_dokument.serijski_broj_ukidanja
Call trenutni_dokument.Save(True, False)

Dim stari As NotesDocument
Dim skup As NotesDocumentCollection

Set skup = db.Search("Form=""certifikat"" & serijski_broj=" +Cstr(broj)  , Nothing, 0)


Set stari = skup.GetFirstDocument

stari.stanje="Aktivan"
Call stari.Save(True, False)

'Dim dateTime As New NotesDateTime( "" )
'dateTime.LSLocalTime = Now
'stari.GetFirstDocument.datum = dateTime.DateOnly 
'Call stari.GetFirstDocument.Save(True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Set skup = db.Search({Form="certifikat" & serijski_broj="} & broj &{"}, Nothing, 0)
```

That will add the value of the item broj of the current document to your search string. I use {} as string delimiter to make the code better readable... I personally don't like the masking of special characters by duplication, I think it makes the code to hard to read.

Comment: im getting type mismatch in method coercestring.
broj = trenutni_dokument.serijski_broj_ukidanja
serijski_broj_ukidanja is a number field. do i need to cast it to string to match search parameters?

Comment: @Ivan: your line should be `broj = trenutni_dokument.serijski_broj_ukidanja(0)`

Comment: If field serijski_broj is really a *number* field then "broj" shouldn't be framed by quotation marks. It should look like this then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23981229/2065611 (isn't that a question from you or a colleague of yours too?)

Comment: thank you, that solved it. I don't know, its a college project due soon so maybe other people have troubles too

Comment: Cool, that's then a really impressive coincidence.